# Online XML parser elements

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

me again, here is my XML

```
<XMLFILE>
<PublishTime>2016-04-30 15:03:40</PublishTime>

<Days>
    <day>
        <Name>Day 1</Name>

        <absentPeople>
            <Absent>
                <Description>Nothing</Description>
                <FullName>Jack Sparrow</FullName>
            </Absent>
        </absentPeople>

    <day>
        <Name>Day 2</Name>

        <absentPeople>
            <Absent>
                <Description>Nothing</Description>
                <FullName>Nobody</FullName>
            </Absent>
        </absentPeople>

</Days>
```

I can read all the names of the days, can someone help me to read the names of the absent people please? To read the names I use this code:

Textview.setText(textview.getText() + "Naam : "
               + getNode("Name", eElement) + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n");

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// Declare variables
TextView textview;
NodeList nodelist;
ProgressDialog pDialog;
// Insert image URL
String URL = "url of xml";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from activity_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Locate a TextView in your activity_main.xml layout
    textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    // Execute DownloadXML AsyncTask
    new DownloadXML().execute(URL);
}

// DownloadXML AsyncTask
private class DownloadXML extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressbar
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        // Set progressbar title
        pDialog.setTitle("Android Simple XML Parsing using DOM Tutorial");
        // Set progressbar message
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressbar
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... Url) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(Url[0]);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            // Download the XML file
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            // Locate the Tag Name
            nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("day");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nodelist.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node nNode = nodelist.item(temp);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                textview.setText(textview.getText() + "Naam : "
                        + getNode("Name", eElement) + "\n" + "\n" + "\n"
                        + "\n");

            }
        }
        // Close progressbar
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

// getNode function
private static String getNode(String sTag, Element eElement) {
    NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0)
            .getChildNodes();
    Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);
    return nValue.getNodeValue();
}
```

}

Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You already know how.

When you have your `<day>` element in the `eElement` variable, you're using `eElement.getElementsByTagName("Name")` to find the `<Name>` tag.

Similarly, you can do `eElement.getElementsByTagName("Absent")` to find all the descendant `<Absent>` tags, iterate them and then call `getNode("FullName", ...)`.